# Realm DB iOS Swift. How can we reorder Result items

Tags: swift, realm

Suppose I have an object like this

```
@objcMembers class MyClass: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var title: String = ""
}
```

I have inserted items into MyClass and fetching like this

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let myClass = realm.objects(MyClass.self)
```

How can I reorder the items in myClass. Or if I have 10 rows in MyClass, how can I change the row order, interchange, move or swap.

Comment: For clarity, using `results.objects` does not return a object class. So myClass in this `let myClass = realm.objects(MyClass.self)` isn't named accurately. It returns a Results object so this is more accurate `let realmResults = realm.objects(MyClass.self)` See the API [Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/10.1.4/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V7objectsyAA7ResultsVyxGxmSo0aB6ObjectCRbzlF) more more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important part of this answer is that:

**Realm Results objects have no guaranteed ordering. What this means is if you load 10 objects 10 times, they may have 10 different orders.**

You need to add a property used for ordering to your object

```
@objcMembers class MyClass: Object {
    dynamic var _id: Int = 0
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var score = 0 //used for ordering
}
```

then load results ordered by score (lower scores are better for this example)

```
let results = realm.objects(MyClass.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "score")
```

support you have three MyClass objects with name properties of Frank with a score of 3, Henry has a score of 10 and Bruce has a score of 20

and you run the above to get those people, they will be ordered by score

```
Frank (score = 3)
Henry (score = 10)
Bruce (score = 20)
```

The suppose Bruce plays again and scores a 7. Update Bruce's score in realm and the results will be updated with the Bruce object in second place

```
Frank (score = 3)
Bruce (score = 7)
Henry (score = 10)
```

So if you want to change the ordering, update whatever property you're ordering by and the results will reflect that new order.

Comment: Thank you @Jay. Ordering addressed my issue. Very helpful